# Google App Dr Edit not opening file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have tried everything to get Google's example Dr Edit(https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/java) to work but to no avail. I'm using the Java version of the app. If you hit my app URL, you can install the app and create a new document in your drive.

https://indigo-cirrus-700.appspot.com

Now try to open a new file. You get an error saying Invalid credentials (missing or invalid oAuth token)

Also if you go to your google drive itself, the app called Dr Edit, does not show up as an option to create a document. Nor does clicking the the txt document that you created via Dr Edit in the previous step start dr edit, just shows the preview.

Finally if you click on manage apps, set as default doesn't show up next to the app.

Its almost like the app isn't installed correctly or the oAuth isn't working correctly Does anyone have any ideas? I ran out

As a side note, I also tried the python example app. Ended up working exactly the same as the java app. You can create a new app via dr edit but thats all.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/?hl=fr), you will need to enable the Picker API for your project. This should solve the "open" issue.

Answer (score 0):

David was right on pointing me the direction of looking into Google picker. Dr edit is an incomplete example. You still need to enable Google Picker and edit controllers.js adding in .setOAuthToken() to the picker. That was missing thereby always giving me missing or invalid oAuth token. To get the oauthtoken onto the page for the call you have to add it to a new scope or just add it to the User scope. Which is what i did.

For python version of dr edit. 
    in main.py User Handler.get() add

```
creds = self.GetSessionCredentials()
if creds:
    result['access_token'] = creds.access_token
```

then in controllers.js MenuCntrl for $scope.open

```
var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=UserCtrl]');
var accessToken = angular.element(appElement).scope().user['access_token']
var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
view.setMimeTypes('text/plain');
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .setAppId(appId)
        .addView(view)
        .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
        .setCallback(angular.bind(this, onFilePicked))
        .build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
```

So the app works well now. Its just the google drive interface not seeing my app as installed and able to open things. Any ideas of what I'm missing?